# Resetting counter in nested loop

Tags: java

I am trying to reset z so z = 0 instead of 2 when it comes out of the inner loop and I want to print 0 1 2 3 instead of just 3 when the loop ends in the outer loop.

```
 int x = 2, y = 4, z = 0, q = 0;
    while (z < y) {
        while (z < x) {
            System.out.print(z + " ");
            z++;
        }
           System.out.println(z + " ");
        z++;
    }
    System.out.println(z + " ");
```

Comment: If I put z = 0 outside the inner loop then it will become an infinite outer loop which certainly I don't want.

Comment: then use `q`. It doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: I ran your code it prints 0 1 2 3 4 on one line (if you use print instead of println).

Comment: You're going to have to apply some logic and reason here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 2, y = 4, z = 0, q = 0;
    while (z < y) {
        while (z < x) {
            System.out.print(z + " ");
            z++;
         }
         if(q == 0){
            z = 0;
            q++;
        }
        System.out.print(z + " ");
        z++;
    }
    System.out.print(z + " ");
}
```

Something like this might be what you are going for.  As crush says you don't use q so when you get to the outer loop create an if statement that keys off a value (i.e  q) to reset z to 0.  Then increment q preventing the if statement being reused thus allowing the loop to end as intended.

When I ran this I got 0 1 0 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0):

Just insert an `if(condition)` in the outer loop to check `if(z==4){z = 0;}`